# Resolving multiple overloads

Tags: c++

I have three overloads of a function that concatenates bits:

```
#include <cstdint>

static uint16_t ConcatenateBits(uint8_t const highPart, uint8_t const lowPart) {
    return ((((uint16_t)highPart) << (sizeof(uint8_t) * 8)) | lowPart);
}
static uint32_t ConcatenateBits(uint16_t const highPart, uint16_t const lowPart) {
    return ((((uint32_t)highPart) << (sizeof(uint16_t) * 8)) | lowPart);
}
static uint64_t ConcatenateBits(uint32_t const highPart, uint32_t const lowPart) {
    return ((((uint64_t)highPart) << (sizeof(uint32_t) * 8)) | lowPart);
}

int main() {
    return ConcatenateBits(7, 3);
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that the compiler is unable to resolve the code in `main` due to the fact that all three overloads are valid for the type `int`. How can I refactor things so that this code works? It would be ideal if I could have a single function (using templates or whatever) that could perform the operation safely across all three types, or possibly more.

Comment: Well, what *should* `ConcatenateBits(7, 3)` return? Personally, I'd give the three functions different names - e.g. `ConcatenateBitsInt8` or something.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Fair question, I was under the impression that it would resolve to the signature of `(uint32_t, uint32_t)` simply because the values passed are `uint32_t`s. In other words: I'd like it to resolve to the type that was actually used.

Comment: @Kittoes0124, I would expect under different situation(cpu, os, etc.) `int` means different size.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. None of the overloads has `(int, int)` signature, so how could it call a function that doesn't exist? Anyway, the thrust of my question was - what numerical value do you expect this call to return, and why? Should it be `7 << 8 + 3` or `7 << 16 + 3` or `7 << 32 + 3`? What if it were `ConcatenateBits(700, 300)`?

Comment: Actually, upon closer inspection, I strongly suspect these functions don't do what you think they do. `sizeof(uint8_t)` is 1, not 8. `sizeof(uint32_t)` is 4, not 32.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Sorry mate, I unintentionally used C# types in my reply. I expect the call to accept the type that was input (if it matches). Also, you are probably correct because I made an assumption with `sizeof` that I really shouldn't have...

Comment: I'm not asking what type the call should return, but what value. In any case, the parameter types of none of the three overloads match `int`, so "same type if it matches" doesn't really help. You seem to want to define the behavior when the type does **not** in fact match.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ah, drat. That is so obvious now... I was just silly thinking that `uint32_t` and `int` resolve to the same thing simply because they have the same size in my environment.

Comment: If nothing else, `int` is signed while `uint32_t` is unsigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using C++17, you can do the following (compiled with command `g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wpedantic main.cc`, using `g++` version 7.3.0 on Debian):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <climits>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename InputType>
constexpr auto ConcatenateBits(InputType highPart, InputType lowPart) {
  constexpr bool is_uint8 = std::is_same<InputType, uint8_t>::value;
  constexpr bool is_uint16 = std::is_same<InputType, uint16_t>::value;
  constexpr bool is_uint32 = std::is_same<InputType, uint32_t>::value;
  static_assert(is_uint8 || is_uint16 || is_uint32,
                "Input type to ConcatenateBits must be uint{8,16,32}_t.");
  if constexpr (is_uint8) {
    uint16_t output = lowPart;
    output |= (static_cast<uint16_t>(highPart) << (sizeof(InputType) * CHAR_BIT));
    return output;
  } else if constexpr (is_uint16) {
    uint32_t output = lowPart;
    output |= (static_cast<uint32_t>(highPart) << (sizeof(InputType) * CHAR_BIT));
    return output;
  } else {
    uint64_t output = lowPart;
    output |= (static_cast<uint64_t>(highPart) << (sizeof(InputType) * CHAR_BIT));
    return output;
  }
}

int main() {
  uint16_t explicitly_typed_variable = 1;
  std::cout << ConcatenateBits(explicitly_typed_variable, explicitly_typed_variable) << "\n";
  std::cout << ConcatenateBits<uint8_t>(1, 2) << "\n";
}
```

With output:

```
65537
258
```

Comment: Thank you! This will definitely help me learn what I wanted; spent a lot of time trying to put together something `constexpr` earlier today but didn't have any luck getting things to compile properly.

Comment: No problem. If this answered your question, feel free to hit the check mark next to my answer, to mark the question as "answered". :)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I refactor things so that this code works?

I can think of the following options:

1. Cast one of the arguments explicitly.

   ```
   return ConcatenateBits(static_cast<uint8_t>(7), 3);
   ```
2. Use a variable instead of a literal.

   ```
   uint8_t v1 = 7;
   return ConcatenateBits(v1, 3);
   ```